# windows 8 javascript app "tapped" event not always working

Tags: javascript, html, events, touch, windows-8.1

i´m testing a Windows 8 app for a touch pannel. 
for now i just want to handle the "tapped" events over the screen.
I´ve tried it with a "MSGesture" object, but the tap events fires the 60%-80% of times. It detects all the "pointerdown" events, but not all of them also trigger a tap event.

Now i´ve tried the same with a "GestureRecognizer" object and the problem remains the same: all the "pointerdown" events fire ok, but not all of them are recognize as tap events.

The Code:

```
gr = new Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer();

        gr.gestureSettings = Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.tap | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.doubleTap;
        gr.addEventListener("tapped", onTap);


        var mainGrid = document.getElementById("mainGrid");
        mainGrid.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown, false);            
        mainGrid.addEventListener('pointermove', processMove, false);
        mainGrid.addEventListener('pointerup', processUp, false);
        mainGrid.addEventListener('pointercancel', processUp, false);






function onPointerDown(e) {
    count++;
    counter.innerHTML = "Count: " + count;
    // Get the current PointerPoint 
    var pp = e.getCurrentPoint(e.currentTarget);

    // Feed the PointerPoint to GestureRecognizer 
    gr.processDownEvent(pp);
}

function processMove(e) {
    // Get the current PointerPoint 
    var pps = e.getIntermediatePoints(e.currentTarget);

    // Feed the PointerPoint to GestureRecognizer 
    gr.processMoveEvents(pps);
}
function processUp(e) {
    // Get the current PointerPoint 
    var pp = e.getCurrentPoint(e.currentTarget);

    // Feed the PointerPoint to GestureRecognizer 
    gr.processUpEvent(pp);
}


function onTap(e) {
    count2++;
    counter2.innerHTML = "Count2: " + count2;        
}
```

As you can see, there are "counter" and "counter2" DOM elements, those are just used for showing a counter that increments each time each event is fired.

Could it be a Windows 8 App performance bug?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you tried with hand.js

Comment: try the tapping without any zoom .. than check the effeciency

Comment: I´ve just tried. But it just handles the pointer events. As i´ve said in my post, the pointer events (like pointerdown) fire pretty well, the problem is that between a pointerdown and a pointerup i need to know if it is a tap, hold, rotate, or any gesture event. And Windows is not identifying them properly (or not always). Thanks.

Comment: Any zoom??? Don´t know what you mean... excuse my ignorance.

Comment: you are testing the app on your window phone. right? you are opening the app in broswer?

Comment: to identify each event try using alert for each event. e.g for hold try alert("try");